# 'last_event VHDL equivalent in verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I'm searching the verilog equivalent of the VHDL attribute `my_signal'last_event`but in Verilog. I have googled it without success. Does someone know how to do it ?

The `'last_event` attribute is used to know the time since the signal last event.
For example, if at time 15us, signal toto toogles from 0 to 1.
Then at time 20us, `toto'last_event` returns 5us.

Comment: When trying to translate from one language to another, it usually helps to have a bigger picture of what you are trying to do. For example, Verilog has built-in timing checks that VHDL does not have that might eliminate the need to do this.

Comment: @dave_59, Yes I have understood that the way I used to write my tests in VHDL is not efficient for verilog. And I've changed this very test to avoid searching for the last event time.

Comment: @dave_59, Are the "Verilog built-in timing check" functions  [these one](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00052.htm) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into some of the verilog system tasks? Specifically the following:

```
$time;                            // Return current simulation time in 64-bit integer 

$monitor("format", v1, v2, ...);  // Invoke only once, and execute (
                                  //   automatically when any of the
                                  //   variables change value.
```

You can look at the 'nested-if-else-if' example here http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/vbehave2.html for an example of a test bench that uses these.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this "monitor" function. Seems usefull for debug, but it's not what I'm looking for. It prints some informations into transcript but the time value is not available in the bench.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a time variable and update it whenever the signal changes

```
time my_signal_last_change;

always @(my_signal) begin
    my_signal_last_change = $time;
end
```

This works in SystemVerilog; not sure if it would in verilog (you can try changing time to reg[63:0] in case it doesn't)

Comment: This is working in quite all situation, but if you check the "my_signal_last_change" value and you expect the very same time as the check time, then depending on the Modelsim's Delta in which the check is made, it's possible that "my_signal_last_change" has not been updated yet.

Comment: Change `time` to `realtime` and `$time` to `$realtime`. $time is an integer limited to the precision of the ``` `timescale ``` where $realtime is a floating point and contains fractional information.